# Escape et-character (&) for output in a LESS loop

Tags: css, loops, less

can't seem to find an answer to this small problem: I have a loop in LESS which I need to output something like this:

```
&#img1 {
  order: 1;
}
```

But I can't figure out how to escape the et char (&) so that it outputs it ... it skips that char. Any ideas? The loop looks like this:

```
@iterations: 10;
.loop (@i) when (@i > 0) {
@txtorder : @i*2;
@imgorder : @i*2-1;
    &#txt@{i} {
        order: ~"@{txtorder}";
    }
    &#img@{i} {
        order: ~"@{imgorder}";
    }
    .loop(@i - 1);
}
.loop (@iterations);
```

Comment: By output, do you mean plain CSS? Plain CSS doesn't do ampersands.

Comment: Just so you know: IDs are unique in a document anyway, so there is no need to add extra specificity to `#selector`, i.e. `&#selector`.

Comment: I mean, when it compiles to normal CSS it should look like this in the css file: &#img1 .... which is no problem for CSS: But LESS uses this char (I guess) and therefor does not output it in the loop.

Comment: @terry ... ahhh ... hmmm, right ... guess I can use it without :-) Thanks, will try that. But would still be nice to learn a solution to the problem for another time :-)

Answer (score 0):

The point is moot ... was mixing css combinators with LESS code - the & is useless in CSS... sorry.